# Draw random numbers from a custom mixture on Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to generate random numbers from a mixture of Gumbel distributions in Matlab differing for location and scale. Could you advise on how to do that?

---

What I know (very little)

1) In Matlab there is a pre-built package to draw from a mixture of Gaussians. For example,

```
clear 

rng default

m=-3;

mu_a = [m, m, m];
sigma_a = [1 0.1 0.5; 0.1 10 0.9; 0.5 0.9 20];

mu_b = -mu_a;
sigma_b= sigma_a;

MU = [mu_a;mu_b];
SIGMA = cat(3,sigma_a,sigma_b);
w = [1/2 1/2]; %equal weight 0.5
obj = gmdistribution(MU,SIGMA,w);

N = 10^4; %number draws
values = random(obj,N);
```

2) In Matlab there is a pre-built package to draw from Gumbel. See [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/evrnd.html)

In general, I couldn't find any Matlab code to draw from a custom mixture in Matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a mixture of 3 Gumbel distributions, each with their own `mu` and `sigma`, and relative `weight` (weights sum to 1), such that the total distribution is:

```
weight(1) * Gumbel(mu(1),sigma(1)) + weight(2) * Gumbel(mu(2),sigma(2)) + weight(3) * Gumbel(mu(3),sigma(3))
```

Then drawing a random value from this distribution is a two-step process:

1. Randomly select one of the 3 distributions to draw a number from.
2. Randomly select a value from the given distribution.

You can implement that this way:

```
mu = [1, 2, 3];
sigma = [0.9, 1.5, 2.1];
weight = [1, 2, 1.5]; weight = weight/sum(weight);

k = rand; % a random value in the range [0, 1];
k = find(k < cumsum(weight), 1, 'first');
random_value = evrnd(mu(k), sigma(k)); % Random value from the Gumbel distribution
```

The above generalizes to any number of distributions, and any type of distribution.

You can vectorize the above to draw `N` random values using:

```
N = 100;
k = rand(N,1); % a random value in the range [0, 1];
[~, k] = max(k < cumsum(weight), [], 2); % find doesn't vectorize nicely, this is an ugly workaround...
random_value = evrnd(mu(k), sigma(k)); % N random values from the Gumbel distributions
```